# SpringBoot Failed to Start app with error (Failed to parse configuration class)

Tags: spring-boot

The spring boot app is running and working fine in local dev area. When I deploy to test environment and try to start the app, I am getting below error. I generated jar file by using gradlew.bat

Any insight on this error? Thanks in advance.

## Error:

```
2021-03-29 23:15:14,283   INFO Version[21] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.7.Final
2021-03-29 23:15:35,502   WARN AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[590] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.org.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
2021-03-29 23:15:35,564   ERROR SpringApplication[856] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.org.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:330)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:563)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at com.org.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:186)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:110)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:463)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

**Here is build.gradle file:**

```
 plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
        id 'java'
    }
    
    
    group = 'abc'
    version = '1.0.0'
    sourceCompatibility = 10
    
    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }
    
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }
    }
    ext {
        set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: spring_boot_starter_validation_version   
        runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: apache_commons_lang_version     
        
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
        compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'
    }   
    
    test {
        outputs.dir snippetsDir
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    
    asciidoctor {
        inputs.dir snippetsDir
        dependsOn test
    }
```

========================================================================================

Answer (score 1):

Error shows that you are having some FTP server related configurations, and those configurations are not working on your test server (or FTP server is not reachable from your test server). Check those configurations, and it will be fine.